# Find the radius of convergence of the Power series $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2^2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{2^4}+\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of the Power series $$1+z+\frac{z^2}{2^2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{2^4}+\frac{z^5}{5!}\cdots $$

Put the series in the form

$$\left[1+\frac{z^2}{2^2}+\frac{z^4}{2^4}+\cdots\right]+\left[z+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}+\cdots\right]
=\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}}\right] +\sinh(z)$$
The radius of convergence of the $1$st series is $4$ and, since $-\infty<\sinh(z)<\infty$, the radius of convergence of the given series is $4$.

Is my approach right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is in the right direction.

The first series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}}$ has radius of convergence 2 - try the root test for example, while the second one has infinite radius of convergence. Thus their sum has radius of convergence equal to 2.

Root test for $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$, where
$$
a_n=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} 2^{-n} & \text{if} & \text{$n$ even}, \\
0 & \text{if} & \text{$n$ odd},
\end{array}\right.
$$
is
$$
\limsup \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}=\frac{1}{2},
$$
and hence radius of convergence$=2$.

Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n}}{2^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$.

Comment: Using root test the radius of convergence becomes 4. How it is 2?

Comment: @SayantanPanja: See edit.

Comment: Here a_n is 1/(2)^(2n). How it is 0 when n is odd?

Comment: @SayantanPanja: No it is not!

Comment: I can not understand the construction of the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$..Please explain clearly ..

Comment: See the last sentence in my answer.